# Regex pattern SyntaxException

Tags: java, android, regex, replaceall, patternsyntaxexception

In my app, I'd like to remove all text in between `"example"` and the first occurance after this of `}` from a string. And I want to do this for all occurences. So I use this code:

```
myString.replaceAll("\"example\"(.+?)}", "");
```

However, this gives me a `PatternSyntaxException`. Why? And: how do I solve it?

stack trace:

```
05-10 23:32:16.129: W/System.err(724): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 16:
05-10 23:32:16.129: W/System.err(724): "example"(.+?)}
05-10 23:32:16.129: W/System.err(724):                 ^
05-10 23:32:16.159: W/System.err(724):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
05-10 23:32:16.190: W/System.err(724):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
05-10 23:32:16.190: W/System.err(724):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
05-10 23:32:16.219: W/System.err(724):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
05-10 23:32:16.219: W/System.err(724):  at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1784)
...
```

Comment: Might you have to escape the brace?

Comment: Could be. How do you do that?

Comment: Well, never mind... I just tried `System.out.println("\"example\" hello world } hello world".replaceAll("\"example\"(.+?)}", ""));` and it worked fine for me. Do you have a stack trace to show?

Comment: @user3580294 Updated the answer with a part of the stack trace

Comment: Hmmm, that's really strange... Perhaps there are some invisible non-ASCII characters that don't show up in the IDE but are in the source file? I've had problems with those in Eclipse before. Try deleting the line and rewriting from scratch. It's really strange that the Pattern compiler would keep looking beyond the end of the regex string....

Comment: Rewritten it from the scratch. Still same problem, and same stack trace. How weird!

Comment: I don't understand why there's the `       ^` in the log file. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm, how strange. What happens if you put a double backslash (`\\` x2) before the last curly brace? (edit: turns out I needed to escape the backslashes here!)

Comment: The `^` is supposed to point to the character that's causing the `PatternSyntaxException`. That's what makes this exception so strange -- the character in question appears to be pointing at nothing in particular.

Comment: Can you post real code example which we could use to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Merlin Also, what version of Java are you running? Your code works just fine for me on 1.8.0_05 and 1.7.0_51

Comment: Yes! Escaping it did the trick! thank you so much for your patience and help! It's really appreciated. Make this an answer so I can accept it please

Comment: No problem! Will do. Glad I could help! Wish I told you how to do the escape first so it didn't have to take so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I don't understand why this gave an exception, but it seems that what you need to do is escape the last curly brace. So instead of

```
myString.replaceAll("\"example\"(.+?)}", "");
```

you do

```
myString.replaceAll("\"example\"(.+?)\\}", "");
                                     ^^
```

The first string worked for me in Java 1.7.0_51 and 1.8.0_05, so I'm not sure how this came about... But it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
"\\\"example\\\"(.+?)}"
```

should work. Your string will be converted to a pattern, which means it will process the escape chars twice. so you need to type `\\` for `\` and `\"` for `"` .

Here is the example http://www.myregextester.com/?r=ab9d1f06

Comment: The thing is the example as provided worked just fine for me, and the issue seems to be that the regex compiler appears to be reading past the end of the regex string...

Comment: And I think the escape chars are actually for the Java compiler, not for the pattern compiler

Comment: This solution didn't help, but thank you for your help anyway!